# Why Ethernet is using CRC-32 and not CRC-32C?

Tags: ethernet, crc, crc32

It has being shown that CRC32C provides better results (an improve Hamming distance and a faster implementation) than CRC32. Why Ethernet is stil using the old CRC 32 and not  CRC32C?

Comment: Probably a legacy issue. Checking all the possible patterns of k bit errors in a message of length n to determine an optimal CRC might have taken an excessive amount of computing time at the time CRC32 was chosen for ethernet. Note that there is still ongoing research for 32 bit and larger CRCs to look for optimal and minimum number of term polynomials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Faster implementation" is not true for the hardware that is normally used to implement the data link layer.

You may be referring to the fact that one particular processor architecture, x86-64, has a CRC instruction that uses the CRC-32C polynomial. However the ARM architecture (aarch64) CRC instruction uses the CRC-32 polynomial. Go figure.

One could argue that yet another polynomial should be used, since Koopman has characterized the performance of many polynomials with better performance than either of the ones you mention. But none of that really matters since ...

All of the legacy hardware has to support the original CRC, and there is little motivation to provide an alternate CRC would use would need to somehow be negotiated between the transmitter and receiver. There is not a noticeable performance advantage for typical noise sources, which are rare single bit errors.

Comment: I doubt any real-world Ethernet MAC does not calculate the CRC in hardware/hdl, so CPU performance doesn't matter.  CRC is relatively cheap in hdl and expensive in CPU instructions. (Unless the CPU has dedicated CRC instructions.)

Comment: I think it may have noticeable performance problems, but rather in noisy technologies such as WiFi.

Comment: @user3563894 No, WiFi uses error correction codes in the physical layer.

Comment: @MarkAdler - pclmulqdq + xmm can also be used for 64 bit CRC, but I haven't investigated this.

Comment: Thank you for the results! I was expecting that the crc32 instruction would be quite a bit faster than folding with pclmulqdq. Indeed it is about five times faster. As for the value, it speeds up gzip decoding, where the faster it is, the less it contributes to the total cpu time.